# FirebaseRecycler How can I not display last one

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working with `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`, I found the features of `limitToLast` or `limitFirstOne`, but I want the specific adapter to not show the last post added.

How can I do so? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then modify the specific adapter as per your requirement. Just override the `getItemCount` method for that specific adapter in which you do not want to show the last element which is returned from firebase.

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return yourList.size() - 1;
}
```

Comment: Great to know that helped! :)